# Material on Fragments and PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an app which requires heavy use of fragments and preferencefragments. But as these things are new to Android, I can not find any good resource to study these except developer.android.com.

developer.android.com provides a good insight, but still after reading preferenceactivity and preferencefragment from there I am a lil bit lost.

So please share some good reference on these topics. (any nice video will be extremely helpful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this YouTube video to understand Fragments:

[Fragments for All: Android Open 2011](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCQ8EcM0HM0)

I hope it makes you understand fragments. You can also check this video tutorial:

[Android 3.0 Activity Fragments Demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-K7NQiIPVgE)